# How to create rings when installing swift on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I am installing **swift** object-server on **ubuntu 12.04** machine and getting some problems.

I've got following error when installing swift:
***IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/swift/object.ring.gz'***

I am not getting how to create/decide **ZONE, DEVICE** and use it in following command:

```
    swift-ring-builder account.builder add z<ZONE>-<STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP>:6002/<DEVICE>    100
    swift-ring-builder container.builder add z<ZONE>-  <STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP_1>:6001/<DEVICE> 100
    swift-ring-builder object.builder add z<ZONE>-<STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP_1>:6000/<DEVICE> 100
```

I tried with **DEVICE as /dev/sda1** (This is primary partition on my m/c, I have another extended partition /dev/sda2 on m/c but don't know how to decide a device), and **ZONE as 1**(Even I don't know how to decide a zone).

Please refer to the this link: [Openstack-Swift Installation & Configuration Ubuntu 12.04](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/installing-and-configuring-the-proxy-node.html)

Can anybody help me out to decide **DEVICE and ZONE?** I think that these must be the only incorrect things I am using so rings are not getting generated.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@Shrikant

I am assuming you are using latest Swift release (havana) from [cloud archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive)

Also see

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
# mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1
# echo "/dev/sdb1 /srv/node/sdb1 xfs noatime,nodiratime,nobarrier,logbufs=8 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
# mkdir -p /srv/node/sdb1
# mount /srv/node/sdb1
# chown -R swift:swift /srv/node
```

Are you having similar partition?